# Sanitizing for header() call?

Tags: javascript, php, sanitization

What security concerns (and ideally sanitization) may there be for `$file` or `$mime` coming from untrusted user input in the following code?

```
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file);
 header("Content-Type: " .  $mime);
```

It's coming back to the supplying user (users who do not have a browser with FileReader), and at least my own JavaScript calling this is sure of the legitimacy of the MIME (I'm pretty sure of the filename, though I'd also like to know if any other characters besides the following disallowed by my Windows 7 machine should not be used for any other modern operating systems: `\/:*?"<>|`). I'm not too concerned therefore about client-side issues, more just whether there are any server-side dangers here...

Comment: How would a HTTP _response_ header pose any server-side danger? Unless you have _any_ server-side component that evaluates the response headers a script is generating, you have nothing to worry about IMHO. (And client-side is no concern at all, because everything any “attacker” would do by sending bogus data would only affect their own client.)

Comment: Great--I would think so, but just wanted to check (especially if one could escape out of and chain headers to add different ones). Do you happen to know about the disallowed characters aspect of the question?

Comment: Well adding additional headers might be possible (don’t actually know how `header()` treats line breaks) – but as I said, they would only be doing that to themselves.

Comment: The caret `^` and ampersand `&` character should probably not be allowed in file names. While they are legitimate characters in file names in most platforms, they can also cause unexpected results if passed unsantized into a shell command (consider a file called `stuff && rm -rf usr`, for example). Although this also come down to: who are you protecting, yourself or you user? Because this would not be a security risk for *you* but it might be a security risk to the client if their code is poorly written.